# storing content of dom elements inside an object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have this function client_choice()  which returns the stored value of dom elements if conditions are met

it iterates over each key and value , the keys and values are the content of dom elements

I tried to declare them outside the function and insert this objects as arguments, which does not work, I tried an click event which does not fire

also inserting them inside the function did not work either

question is how do i pass the content of the dom elements to the function ?

```
 let file1 = $('#select_updateFile option:selected').text();
    let file2 = $('#select_updateFile option').eq(2).text();

    let column = $('.column_select option:selected').text();
    // condition
    let condition = $('.condition_select option:selected').text();



    let update_data = {file1: column};
    let conditon_data = {file2: condition};
```

```
function client_choice() {
    const keyCondtion_true = (currentValue) => currentValue !== "select column" && currentValue !== "";
    const valueCondition_true= (currentValue) => currentValue !== "select column" && currentValue !== "";
   
// variables
 

    let meta_data = {...update_data, ...conditon_data};

    if (Object.keys(meta_data).every(keyCondtion_true) && Object.values(meta_data).every(valueCondition_true)) {

        return {"update": update_data, "condition": conditon_data}


    } else {
        console.log("both wrong")
        return false

    }

}
```

html

```
<select name="selectFile" id="selectFile">
    <option value="">choose File</option>
    <option class="file1" value="col1.xlsx">file1.txt</option>
    <option class="file2" value="col2.xlsx">file2.xlsx</option>
</select>

<select name="column_select" class="columselect">
    <option value="">choose Columns</option>
    <option class="column" value="column1">column1</option>
    <option class="column" value="column2">column2</option>
    <option class="column" value="column3">column3</option>
    <option class="column" value="column4">column4</option>
</select>



<select name="condition_select" class="condition_select">
    <option value="">choose condtiton</option>
    <option class="condtiton" value="condtiton1">condtiton1</option>
    <option class="condtiton" value="condtiton2">condtiton2</option>
    <option class="condtiton" value="condtiton3">condtiton3</option>
    <option class="condtiton" value="condtiton4">condtiton4</option>
</select>



<button type="button" id="button">click me !!!</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```